# Spinor transformation matrix derivation

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, matrix-elements

The spinor in the Dirac equation should transform via a 4x4 matrix $S$ that depends on the specific Lorentz boost/rotation:

$\psi '(x')=S(\Lambda )\psi(x)\tag1$

Where S satisfies:

$S^{-1}\gamma ^{\mu }S=\gamma ^{\nu }\Lambda _{\nu  }^{\mu }\tag2$

(Where the $\gamma^{\mu}$ are the gamma matrices) As to ensure Lorentz invariance of the Dirac equation.

If we start by considering an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation:

$\Lambda _{\nu  }^{\mu }=\delta_{\nu  }^{\mu }+\omega _{\nu  }^{\mu }\tag3$

That, upon lowering indices, gives:

$\Lambda _{ \mu\nu }^{}=\eta_{\mu\nu  }+\omega _{\mu\nu  }\tag4$

Where $\omega _{\mu\nu  }$ is antisymmetric.

$\omega _{\mu\nu  }=-\omega _{\nu\mu  }\tag5$

We shall make the assumption that:

$S=I-\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\mu\nu}\tag6$

Where the $\beta ^{\mu\nu}$ are all 4x4 matrices.

In for example this paper:
https://physicspages.com/pdf/Lahiri%20QFT/Lahiri%20&%20Pal%20Problems%2004.04.pdf

It is stated that these $\beta ^{\mu\nu}$ satisfy:

$\left [\gamma ^{\mu},\beta^{\lambda\rho} \right ]=2i(\eta ^{\mu\lambda}\gamma^{\rho}-\eta ^{\mu\rho}\gamma^{\lambda})\tag6$

For which I cannot find a proof anywhere...

My attempt is to try and stick this $S$ into $(2)$:

$S^{-1}=I+\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\mu\nu}\tag7$

So $2$ becomes:

$(I+\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\omega_{\alpha\nu})\gamma^{\mu}(I-\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\phi\theta}\omega_{\phi\theta})=\gamma^{\nu}(\delta_{\nu  }^{\mu }+\omega _{\nu  }^{\mu })\tag8$

Expanding and ignoring the term that would be second-order in $\omega$:

$\gamma^{\mu}+\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}-\frac{i}{4}\gamma^{\mu}\beta ^{\phi\theta}\omega_{\phi\theta}=\gamma^{\mu}+\gamma^{\nu}\omega _{\nu  }^{\mu }\tag9$

Cancelling the $\gamma$'s and lower the $\mu$ on the $\omega$ on the right-hand side:

$\frac{i}{4}\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}-\frac{i}{4}\gamma^{\mu}\beta ^{\phi\theta}\omega_{\phi\theta}=\gamma^{\nu}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\omega _{\alpha\nu  }\tag{10}$

Relabelling and seperating out the $\omega$'s and multiplying by $4i$:

$-\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}+\gamma^{\mu}\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}=4i\gamma^{\nu}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\omega _{\alpha\nu  }\tag{11}$

Which is where I am stuck... I'm quite sure I have to use the antisymmetry but I can't see how exactly.

Comment: Are you trying to prove : $\left [\gamma ^{\mu},\beta^{\lambda\rho} \right ]=2i(\eta ^{\mu\lambda}\gamma^{\rho}-\eta ^{\mu\rho}\gamma^{\lambda})$ ?

Comment: Yes I am indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a little thing : using the anti-symmetric property of $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ as shown below $\rightarrow$
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\gamma^{\nu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\beta ^{\alpha\nu}\omega_{\alpha\nu}&=4i\gamma^{\nu}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\omega _{\alpha\nu} \\
&= 2i \gamma^\nu \eta^{\alpha\mu}(\omega_{\alpha\nu} - \omega_{\nu\alpha})
\end{aligned}
$$

I am sure you can derive the result from here. If not, please get back to me and I will update my answer with full solution.

As an aside, do note that since $\eta$ is symmetric and $\mu$ is anti-symmetric the term $\sim \eta^{\alpha\mu}\omega _{\alpha\nu}$ can only be non zero if both of them appear in this term with same behaviour of sign under exchange of indices.

Comment: Wait, are the beta's antisymmetric?

Comment: @StijnBoshoven Yes, since $\omega$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: but $\beta^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\mu\nu}=-\beta^{\nu\mu}\omega_{\mu\nu}$ does not mean that $\beta^{\mu\nu}=-\beta^{\nu\mu}$ right? In the same way that $\eta^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\mu\nu}=-\eta^{\nu\mu}\omega_{\mu\nu}$ does not mean that $\eta^{\mu\nu}=-\eta^{\nu\mu}$

Comment: @StijnBoshoven You can write $\beta^{\mu\nu}$ as a sum of symmetric part and an antisymmetric part. Since $\omega^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric the symmetric part of $\beta^{\mu\nu}$ will give zero when contracted with  $\omega^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Ahh genius, when assuming step $(6)$ we basically assumed that the $\beta$'s are antisymmetric! Thank you so much, I've got it now

Comment: @StijnBoshoven I personally think that in general $\beta^{\mu\nu}$ can be a general rank-2 tensor but since we are defining them from the eq(6a) we take them antisymmetric because the symmetric part is not going to have any effect on S, which is what we care about. It would be interesting to see if there are any consequences of having a symmetric part in $\beta^{\mu\nu}$. Did you use it's antisymmetricity to derive eq(6b)?

Comment: yes I managed to derive $(6)$

Comment: I mean, did you have to use the antisymmetric nature of $\beta^{\mu\nu}$ to derive it or not?

Comment: yes, I just wrote down $(11)$ and said let me take $\omega_{01}$ as the only nonzero $\omega$. Then I put it in the form of $(6)$ using (I think you have to use it but I'm no expert) the antisymmetry of the $\omega$'s and $\beta$'s and cancelled the $\omega$'s. Then I turned all the $0$ indices into $\rho$ indices and $1$ indices into $\lambda$ indices which is allowed because I could've picked any other $\omega$ to have been the only nonzero one